# Android surfaceview onTouchEvent limiting?

Tags: android, multithreading, sleep, surfaceview, touch-event

When you have a surfaceView class, used for animation/game/... you have the onTouchEvent() method and the drawing/screen-refreshing method in that same class. Now I want to just sleep the onTouchEvent method, so it doesn't get called +-80 times a second and flooding the cpu (and therefor causing lag). The problem is that if I sleep this class, it also stops drawing.

**Edit88
I'M Trying to stop onTouchEvent() to be called too frequently. my attempt:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
Log.d("firstTest",Integer.toString(event.getAction()));   //shows up
if (!sleeper.CurrentlySleeping) {
    Log.d("2ndTest",Integer.toString(event.getAction())); //not showing up
    ~~  some calculations and stuff  ~~
```

.

```
public class TouchSleeper extends Thread {
// If Thread is sleeping or not.
public static Boolean CurrentlySleeping;
public TouchSleeper() {
CurrentlySleeping = false;
this.setPriority(MIN_PRIORITY);
}

@Override
public void run() {
try {
    while (true) {
        CurrentlySleeping = true;
        TouchSleeper.sleep(50);
        CurrentlySleeping = false; }
    ~end~
```

First a piece of code from my SurfaceView class. Second piece of a class/thread, wich keeps changing a boolean value. Note how my first Log.d does return something, and the second one doesn't. This tells me that CurrentlySleeping is never false ? I still have not figured things out... ?

Comment: Why are you getting 80 touch events per second?

Comment: Well, when you touch the screen, it's called automatically just as fast as the cpu can handle it. This usually is very often, and cost's alot of cpu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be simpler not to listen to the onTouch events in the first place instead of blocking out the processing code when the onTouch event does occur, in this case you will still have an overhead of the function getting called (and in this case when you don't want it)

So implement the `onTouchListener` interface and set it for the view using `setOnTouchListener`. Now when you don't want to listen to any onTouch events for a view set it to NULL.

Now instead of using sleep, try using an Alarm or post a delayed message to your thread handler to reset the `onTouchListener` for the view at a later point of time. (Personally, I think it is much neater than sleep :) )

Comment: How do you mean "set it to NULL"? How do you do that ?

Comment: Exactly how it sounds, `<viewInstance>.setOnTouchListener(null)`. When you don't want to listen to certain events you need to unregister yourself, since there is no such thing as unregistering in android just set the listener to null;

Answer (score 0):

If the class has an onTouchEvent method you cannot prevent it from being called.  Just have onTouchEvent return false and do nothing else.